# Visual Basic - Referencia de objeto no establecida en una instancia de un objeto

Tags: vb.net

Quiero mandar a llamar un SP de otra clase para comparar uno de sus campos, pero al instanciarlo y convertirlo en un objeto parece que estoy generando mal la instancia.

```
private Objeto As New Propiedades

Dim obj As Propiedades = New BP.Libreria.ClaseDos().MetodoObtener(currentSelected.PkEstudio, currentSelected.AnioRenov, False, False)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!